# Trying to achieve folder count

Tags: powershell, textbox

I'm trying to count a folder but with two different condition.
if Box 1 has Name then shows count but if not will show only dash "-"

```
{
if($TextBox02 -eq $True)
{your text
  $ResultBox2.Text = "Good"
}
else
{
  $ResultBox2.Text = "-"
}
}
```

[image]

What I got was only blank.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TextBox02.Text)) {` but without seeing the rest of the code or having a way to reproduce the issue is hard to tell

Comment: Hello Santiago Squarzon,
i have tried the code. it worked. thats what Im looking for..
thank You Sir